# Can we replace transformer in the DAB converter with some inductor model

Tags: power-supply, transformer, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, inductive

I am currently working on analyzing the behavior of GaN MOSFETs in a Dual Active Bridge (DAB) converter for a battery charging application. The DAB converter requires a transformer for isolation and power transformation purposes. However, I am facing difficulties in obtaining a commercially available transformer, as a custom design order is required.

I am seeking your expertise and insights on possible alternatives to replace the transformer in the DAB converter. Are there any viable options, such as using other inductor models or similar components, that can serve the purpose of isolation and power transformation in the DAB converter?

I want to implement in hardware level.

[image]

Comment: Please draw a circuit with the tool of DAB controller

Comment: I'm confused - is this about simulation or testing?  Unfortunately we can't discuss topics here; EE.SE is strictly question-and-answer.

Comment: I will implement hardware.

Comment: Or about obtaining a source for a transformer? Or modeling a commercial transformer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any viable options, such as using other inductor models or
> similar components, that can serve the purpose of isolation and power
> transformation in the DAB converter?

The two ways of achieving isolation are capacitive and inductive (with transformers).

You could potentially build a converter that uses capacitive means to transfer energy but you might not be able to get the power through it as you may need a large cap.